# Extra trailing comma in Header

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, iis-8

I have a Cordova application connecting to IIS.  I am getting an extra comma when I send:

```
$rootScope.httpConfig = {
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'authorization': 'bearer ' + response.Token
  }
};
```

The token has no commas, somewhere in the pipe between the client and the server a comma is being appended.  Any ideas why?

For now, in my IDispatchMessageInspector, I am testing for an removing the trailing comma.

```
if (authTokenJson.EndsWith(",")) authTokenJson =
  authTokenJson.Remove(authTokenJson.Length - 1);
```